# How does Java disable a specific compilation optimization algorithm (for example GVN)

Tags: java, compilation, jvm

For some reasons, I want to know the effect of a specific optimization algorithm (GVN) in Java.

My idea about how to do is to run a benchmark before and after disabling this algorithm. And then compare the time and space consumption. But I don't know how to disable GVN in Java compilation.

Is there any compiler parameters to do this? Or any other methods to find out the effect of a specific optimization algorithm?

And my jdk is jdk11 with fast debug build. Thanks!

Comment: What is GVN? Perhaps it could be expanded a bit?

Comment: Global Value Numbering. An algorithm that the java compiler will use when doing compilation optimization.

Comment: If you can't find the option in the `java` command documentation, you could try looking through the OpenJDK source code.  (It sounds like you have already downloaded it to create your build ...)

Comment: I don’t think that you can turn it off in isolation. You could turn off the C2 compiler, but that would have more impact than just turning off GVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GVN is not just an optimization - this is a fundamental compilation phase that many other optimizations depend on. There is no JVM switch to turn off GVN in HotSpot C2 compiler.

However, there is a flag `-XX:-UseGlobalValueNumbering` for C1 compiler. This flag is available only in debug builds of the JVM.